# Toggling favorite item(s) on a list of items - how can i autosave items by the user, without using a submit <input>

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have a list of items displayed on a web page and i want the user to be able to favorite items on that list and for it to autosave/update in the db.  How could this be done without having a submit input/btn?

```
function myStar(id) {
document.getElementById("Star_"+ id).classList.toggle("hidestar");
document.getElementById("Starfill_"+ id).classList.toggle("showstar");
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myStar(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.classList.toggle("favourite-item");
}
</script>

<a href="#" onClick="myStar(event)">STAR</a>
```